# Python: Pandas.DataFrame with comma thousands separator

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with both float values and integers. I want the integers to be printed with a comma thousands separator and floats rounded to two decimal places. Below is an excerpt of my DataFrame with floats rounded but without the comma thousands separator.

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
pd.DataFrame(d)

            null_n  datatype    col_min col_mean    col_median  col_max col_std
assetCode   0       object      nan     nan         nan         nan     nan
assetName   0       category    nan     nan         nan         nan     nan
close       0       float64     0.07    39.71       30.30       1578.13 42.29
open        0       float64     0.01    39.71       30.29       9998.99 42.61
```

The dataframe is built from multiple Pandas.Series: `null_n`, `datatype`, `col_min`, etc. So I thought I could either 1. convert the integer Series into a string with columns, or 2. alter the way the Pandas dataframe is printed. I don't know how to do 1. or 2. I have seen:

```
print '{:,}'.format(n)

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
locale.format('%d', 1000000, 1)
```

but neither works for my use case.

Comment: Can you also add the code to reproduce your dataframe?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @ChrisA has the right approach for floats. For ints it's a pain. Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663252/format-pandas-integers-for-display

Comment: @David that's exactly what I needed, thanks.