# How do I custom format a pandas integer column to display with commas as thousands separators?

Tags: python, pandas, separator, custom-formatting

I've got a dataframe column `GDP/year` from a dataset about suicides over some years. The data type of this column is currently object (string), but I want it as integer.

The values are commas separated so I can't directly transform them to integers. I tried string-removing the commas, storing as integer, then I  introduce the commas again, but its the type reverts back to object.

The dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/russellyates88/suicide-rates-overview-1985-to-2016

```
# convert to int...
suicides[' gdp_for_year ($) '] = suicides[' gdp_for_year ($) '].str.replace(',','').astype(int) 
# now reformat with commas as thousands separator...
suicides[' gdp_for_year ($) '] = suicides[' gdp_for_year ($) '].astype(int).apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x)) 
# ...wanted to get dtype integer, but it's back to object
```

Comment: I am not sure why you run the second line of the code? The first converts the data to `int` dtype which is what you want. The second line will convert it it back to string as @rusu_ro1 said

Comment: I think you should add also pandas tag

Comment: Type "object" means "string". Now, you need to **distinguish between the underlying data (e.g. the integer 1234) and its (string) representation e.g. `1,234`**. pandas allows you to define custom formatters on a per-column basis, which is what you're asking for here. **You can (and should) store integer data as integer data, just define a custom formatter for it**. As for the underlying code for [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Comment: Related: [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are converting to string each element : `"{:,}".format(x)`

but I guess you want to display your numbers in your pandas DataFrame to show comma separators by default, for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102734/format-a-number-to-commas-to-separate-thousands-in-python) you can do it but for float data type:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,}'.format
```

if  you want also for int type you should  [monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663252/format-pandas-integers-for-display) `pandas.io.formats.format.IntArrayFormatter` .

Comment: Note this causes **all** columns to use `,` as thousands separator. OP said they only wanted the formatting on this one specific column. So you need a custom formatter for this column.